# Mysql filter out groups containing unwanted items

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. One contains list of ordered products with some data. Another is just a list of orders with count of products in every order.
I would like to select only orders (order_id) which must contain product_id 1 (may include other products) and none of individual product in order does not contain "Y" in product_data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT op.order_id
FROM order_products op
JOIN orders o ON o.order_id = op.order_id
WHERE o.product_count = 3 AND op.id = 1 
GROUP BY op.order_id
```

How to filter out orders that contain products with "Y" in product_data? Thank you.
Expected result should be: order_id 2

order_products

| order_id | product_id | product_data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | x |
| 1 | 2 | x |
| 1 | 3 | Y |
| 2 | 1 | x |
| 2 | 2 | x |
| 2 | 5 | x |
| 3 | 50 | x |

orders

| order_id | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |

Comment: Please post your expected data.

Comment: Why do you use the condition `o.product_count = 3` in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL deals in sets of rows. So think about sets of `order_id` values.

This subquery generates the set of `order_id` values that have the `'Y'` in their product_data column.

```
      SELECT order_id FROM order_products WHERE product_data = 'Y';
```

Use that set to filter your results.  Like this. [Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa438d/2).

```
SELECT DISTINCT op.order_id
  FROM order_products op
  JOIN orders o ON o.order_id = op.order_id
 WHERE op.product_id = 1
  AND o.order_id NOT IN (
      SELECT order_id FROM order_products WHERE product_data = 'Y');
```

You don't need both DISTINCT and GROUP BY in this query.

Answer (score 0):

Just use WHERE AND clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT op.order_id
FROM order_products op
JOIN orders o ON o.order_id = op.order_id
WHERE o.product_count = 3 AND op.id = 1 AND op.product_data = 'Y'
GROUP BY op.order_id
```

Comment: WHERE after group by does not work

Comment: Oh, use this 
SELECT DISTINCT op.order_id
FROM order_products op
JOIN orders o ON o.order_id = op.order_id
WHERE o.product_count = 3 AND op.id = 1 AND op.product_data = 'Y'
GROUP BY op.order_id